# Writing script for college sports class, keep getting error 'AttributeError: module 'scrapy' has no attribute 'spider''

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

This is my code, not sure what I am doing wrong here. Appreciate any help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
import requests
import time
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all?filters%5B0%5D=status%3A23'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Applications/Python 3.9/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

class WebSpider(scrapy.spider):
    name = "Web_Spider"
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.ufc.com/athletes']
    start_urls = ['https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all?filters%5B0%5D=status%3A2']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = driver

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            next = self.drive.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="block-mainpagecontent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/a')

            try:
                next.click()

            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()
```

I keep getting the error 'AttributeError: module 'scrapy' has no attribute 'spider''. Not sure what to do here, Scrapy is installed correctly and up-to-date.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending what you are trying to do, I wouldn't go with Selenium here as you can fetch the data directly through ajax. Selenium will still work but it's a bit overkill and less efficient.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


url = 'https://www.ufc.com/views/ajax?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

page = 1
end_of_load = False
while end_of_load == False:
    payload = {
    'view_name': 'all_athletes',
    'view_display_id': 'page',
    'view_path': '/athletes/all',
    'pager_element': '0',
    'gender': 'All',
    'page': '%s' %page}
    
    
    jsonData = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
    print('Page: %s' %page)
    page += 1
    
    html = jsonData[-1]['data']

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    
    player_cards = soup.find_all('div',{'class':re.compile('.*view-mode-all-athletes-result.*')})
    if not player_cards:
        end_of_load = True
  
    else:
        for player_card in player_cards:
            name = player_card.find('span',{'class':re.compile('.*athlete__name.*')}).text.strip()
            try:
                weight_class = player_card.find('div',{'class':re.compile('.*weight-class.*')}).text.strip()
            except:
                weight_class = 'N/A'
            try:
                record = player_card.find('span',{'class':re.compile('.*athlete__record.*')}).text.strip()
            except:
                record = 'N/A'
            print('\t%s - %s\t%s' %(name,weight_class,record))
```

Comment: Thank you this worked great! Would you happen to know any good tutorials one explaining the 'ajax?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax', and how to work with this? I didn't even know you could get the data directly through AJAX as I was under the assumption AJAX was just a way to load the screen without changing URLs.

Comment: I don't really know of a tutorial (which actually makes me think I should make one!). If you do a google search of like "python web scrape through api". But I really only learned by practice and learning by exactly what you are doing, and seeing solutions on SO.

Comment: Absolutely! I would definitely watch/read a tutorial! Thank you, I will search it up and hopefully one day I can identify elements like you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It's scrapy.Spider, with capital "s"

Answer (score 1):

```
Try now: 

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
import requests
import time
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all?filters%5B0%5D=status%3A23'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Applications/Python 3.9/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

class WebSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Web_Spider"
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.ufc.com/athletes']
    start_urls = ['https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all?filters%5B0%5D=status%3A2']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = driver

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            next = self.drive.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="block-mainpagecontent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/a')

            try:
                next.click()

            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()
```